# Nextag API - SimpleXML won't work

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I'm trying to pull in data from Nextag using their relatively simple api.

You can see an example XML response by visiting:

http://api.nextag.com/buyer/synd.jsp?token=AgAg-V6vGl$rkqkUtxvd&ver=15&search=LG%2047LE8500

But I can't get Simple XML to work right with this data.  I either get a constructor error or an empty object.

Here's what I have so far:

$xml = file_get_contents('http://api.nextag.com/buyer/synd.jsp?token=AgAg-V6vGl$rkqkUtxvd&ver=15&search=LG%2047LE8500');

$simple_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

And $simple_xml is always an empty object.

Is there something wrong with the response data?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is Simple XML just incompatible and if so, what should I do instead?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: Sean's answer was useful in that it helped get past the error, but the data is not being loaded, only the partial structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to tell it the namespace you want to parse. This seems to work:

```
$simple_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, null, false, 'nxtg', true);
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is useful, but it doesn't get it quite there yet.  None of the actually data is contained in the object.  And it looks like it only loads the first child of each tag, but still without data.  So the structure is getting partially created, but with none of the data.

Comment: Hmmm, when I run it, I get data in the resulting object structure. If you print_r($simple_xml), what is the output?